# Multidimensional Array Can Contain Single Element or Another Array. How to traverse?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This has been racking my brain for a few days. I thought I had a solution but I am finding it difficult to come up with an always working bullet proof piece of code. I am traversing a multidimensional array. I have two functions, one that looks at a single row and one that looks at an array. I have two poetential configurations for an array.

**First Example**

```
[
    'Person' => [
        'Name' => 'John Smith'
    ]
]
```

(One single result for person, with only one name for that person.)

**Second Example**

```
[
    'Person' => [
        'Name' => [
            0 => 'John Smith',
            1 => 'John Denver'
        ]
    ]
]
```

(One single person, with multiple names for that person.)

**Third Example**

```
[
    'Person' => [
         0 => [
             'Name' => 'John Smith'
         ],
         1 => [
             'Name' => 'Jane Doe'
         ]
    ]
]
```

(Two people, each with one name only.)

**Fourth Example**

```
[
    'Person' => [
         0 => [
             'Name' => [
                 0 => 'John Smith',
                 1 => 'John Denver'
             ]
         ],
         1 => [
             'Name' => 'Jane Doe'
         ]
    ]
]
```

(Two people, the first one has two names, the second only has one.)

Hopefully this is understood what I am saying. When there is only 1 record for something, it will return the single record. If there is more than one record, there will be an array containing each of those records.

I need to transverse through the multidimensional array from beginning to end. I am trying to figure out exactly how to check if there is one single answer or multiple.

I have tried checking for array key names, checking if keys are integers vs strings and if something is an array or not.

Nothing is quite working out as I expect. Can anyone help provide a way to transverse and check using for example a *foreach loop* or a function?

If it helps, I have another array that contains the names of the key fields that it is trying to look for. That array would have a similar layout to this:

```
[
    'Person' => [
        'type' => 'array',
        'subfields' => [
             'Name' => [
                 'type' => 'string'
              ]
         ]
     ]
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Since this wasn't clear. I am looking for how to make the parent key apply to the child value independently of whether or not the value is a single value, or if it is an array of multiple values. The key parent needs to apply to all children, unless there is another parent key (there could be in theory an unlimited number of children / parent keys underneath a parent key.

**Final**

I managed to figure this out. Thank you to everyone for your help.

Comment: I didn't get your question , i got all the four arrays which you have posted at the top, then what is your expected output now?

Comment: Not sure if you have the option to do so, but it will be a lot easier for you and anyone in the future if the results are standardized. What I mean is, the fourth example is always used, no matter how many people or names there are.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. I am trying to make it as robust as possible and allowing for many different possibilities.This code will be for decoding HTML/XML tags that are put into arrays and I want to be able to handle whatever is thrown at it.

Comment: I think your question is unclear. You mention to @SahilGulati that you don't want to collect the names, but instead want to traverse the array and return the same exact array. This begs the question, why are you traversing it in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a more complete example - an array with a few of the example structures included, and then the corresponding output you're looking for from this input.

Comment: To be very specific. I am transversing the array to check each and every value against another array of rules. There are predefined rules that check and type cast strings, integers, floats, boolean.. etc. So the overall class/function returns an array with the same format, but not necessary the same content. You may have a string that is "TRUE", but the rules are looking for a boolean, so it will convert it to a literal TRUE constant value. I have all that stuff already written, which is why I didn't include those portions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get a list of people, you can normalise your data with **array_walk_recursive** to return this to sanity as a list of names from either format.

```
function normaliseData($peopleData) {
    $people = []; 
    array_walk_recursive($peopleData, function($item, $key) use(&$people) {    
        $people[] = $item;        
    });
    return $people;
}
print_r(normaliseData($first)); // Array ( [0] => John Smith )
print_r(normaliseData($second)); // Array ( [0] => John Smith [1] => John Denver )
print_r(normaliseData($third)); // Array ( [0] => John Smith [1] => Jane Doe )
print_r(normaliseData($fourth)); // Array ( [0] => John Smith [1] => John Denver [2] => Jane Doe )
```

Comment: The problem with the array_walk_recursive is that we will be throwing lots of very different arrays at it, they will never be as basic as this, and in some cases key names will be reused at different levels of the multi-multi-multi-dimensional array.

Comment: This will handle the four test cases listed. If we can't anticipate the formats in which the data is received, I don't see how it's possible to write a solution. It's solving the problem from the wrong end. The data should ideally be normalised by some mechanism into an expected format.

Comment: I believe you were under the impression that the array would always be the same. What I am ultimately looking for is a way to hit every single value, and also know when a key has more than one value. So in the case of something like example #4, it would know that there are two names for that one person. We need to link the "Name" key to either a single non-array value or apply the name key to each sub value of that multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

For this `array_walk_recursive` is the best option as the post of `@JasonBoss` works, but if want to do it manually from a function you can do it like this.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785232)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array1=[
    'Person' => [
        'Name' => 'John Smith'
    ]
];
$array2=[
    'Person' => [
        'Name' => [
            0 => 'John Smith',
            1 => 'John Denver'
        ]
    ]
];
$array3=[
    'Person' => [
         0 => [
             'Name' => 'John Smith'
         ],
         1 => [
             'Name' => 'Jane Doe'
         ]
    ]
];
$array4=[
    'Person' => [
         0 => [
             'Name' => [
                 0 => 'John Smith',
                 1 => 'John Denver'
             ]
         ],
         1 => [
             'Name' => 'Jane Doe'
         ]
    ]
];

$result=array();
getRecords($array1);
print_r($result);

$result=array();
getRecords($array2);
print_r($result);

$result=array();
getRecords($array3);
print_r($result);

$result=array();
getRecords($array4);
print_r($result);


function getRecords($array)
{
    global $result;
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_string($value))
        {
            $result["names"][]=$value;
        }
        elseif(is_array($array[$key]) && count($array[$key]))
        {
            getRecords($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this case, it cannot handle other cases such as when something isn't a string. Could the is_string function be replaced with a !is_array function and have it work similarly?

Comment: I went back and looked at it, and unfortunately the code doesn't work as expected. Our goal isn't to collect the names of the people, but just to traverse the array through to every value and to return the same exact array as what was presented. 

Here is a change I made that I thought would work, but as you can see there is some strange behavior on Array #4 for example. https://eval.in/785854